# Create outlets and code programatically in XCode

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

I find it very tedious having to create connections and other repeatable stuff in XCode 4. This just does not seem RAD to me. Let me explain

I have a View based iPad project with a single view. 
On the view are about 50 buttons and 50 UIImage objects - total 100 objects. All the UIImage objects have the same image. All the buttons have the same Action. The tag of each button determines the code to run in the Action.

What I find tedious is:

1. I have to type in a "tag" for each of the objects - 100 tags
2. I have to drag each object to make an outlet which produces code like this in the .h file:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   @interface bbTestViewController : UIViewController {
       UIImageView *pop1;
       UIImageView *pop2;
       UIImageView *pop3;
       UIImageView *pop4;
       UIImageView *pop5;
       etc....
   ```

   for the 50 controls and also this code below:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pop1;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pop2;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pop3;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pop4;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pop5;
   etc....
   ```

   for the 50 controls.

and in the .m file:

```
    @synthesize pop1;
    @synthesize pop2;
    @synthesize pop3;
    @synthesize pop4;
    @synthesize pop5;
    etc.....
```

This also adds lines like this:
        - (void)viewDidUnload
        {

```
        [self setPop1:nil];
        [self setPop2:nil];
        [self setPop3:nil];
        [self setPop4:nil];
        [self setPop5:nil];
        etc.....
```

and

```
    - (void)dealloc {
        [pop1 release];
        [pop2 release];
        [pop3 release];
        [pop4 release];
        [pop5 release];
        etc.....
```

3.Then for each of the 50 buttons I have to drag them to the the same Action to make the connection, select the touch action, type a name and then click OK.

This I find tedious and counter productive. Not RAD at all. More SAD. So much of repeating the same actions, it is painful.

So the Question is, is there an easier way. I do not believe in Copy/Paste so that solution is a no-no.

In other languages I would use a For...Each to iterate thru every object and do the needful.

e.g. for the tag:
I would have code to set the tags like this:

```
    Integer n = 1;
    For Each oObject in myView
        oObject.tag = n
        n = n+1
    end for
```

So can I use code to get around these tedious processes of

1. tag
2. Declaring each object and adding the @property... code
   adding the @synthesize... code
   setting each object to nil
   releasing each object
3. Somehow automate the connection from all the buttons to the Action.

I want to be able to do all this in code and without all that copy/paste stuff or those repeatable actions in IB for XCode 4 by dragging to make a connection.

Is this at all possible in this MVC system that XCode 4 uses? If so, how?

**Update**
After some research I found at least one answer to my Q - with regard to Connections to Actions.

It appears that if you add an object - say a button and make a connection to an action in IB, then if you copy and paste that button (or any such object), IB RETAINS the connections made so in my case above, I create the button and make the connection to the Action and if I copy and paste it, IB will make the connections to the same Action for every pasted button. At least that will save some time. HTH others.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about one thing IB sucks royally.  I had high hopes that Apple would have done more to fix it in XCode 4.x.

However I do wonder about your interface.  Having 50 buttons on one view seems to be a little much.  So you might want to refactor that aspect of your project.

As to your current issue, do realize that you can build an app without IB.   You do need to learn how to programiclly build the controls and do the layout.  I'd suggest looking at sample code from Apple first.

Still I'd suggest thinking long and hard about those 50 buttons.

Comment: It's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: I know that 50 buttons is 47 too many:) the project is a starter i am doing to learn. The buttons are in a grid 7x9. Would not normally use that many in a normal proj.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn something you are not planning to use in a normal proj?

Comment: Because learning is how I go about things. Whether it is a few buttons or many is not exactly the point here to my Q. I wanted to know if I could create the repetitious code pragmatically and whether I could create the connections to the outlets/actions without the tedious dragging and linking method of xcode. On a form I might expect to have not 50 buttons but possibly a large number of other objects and drag-link is not productive.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    xpos = ...; // appropriate coordinate go here
    ypos = ...; // appropriate coordinate go here
    [button setFrame: CGRectMake(xpos, xpos, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    [button addTarget: self action: @selector(myCoolAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag: i];
    [[self view] addSubview: button];
}
```

and you should be fine. Same for the images...

Comment: No that will not do. How would i put in the x,y coords in a loop for different controls. Besides the code is for creating the buttons at runtime. I prefer the visual approach to design, but wanted to avoid all that repitious work IB forces me to make. So un-RAD.

Comment: 1. `xpos = xpos + buttonHeight + 5.0f;` 2. How should IB know which action belongs to which button when you don't want to tell?

Comment: xpos = xpos + buttonHeight + 5.0f;That would only work for evenly located buttons/objects. not for objects arranged all over the view where the difference in the xpos is not a fixed value. And I want to tell it which action is which button but in code instead of drag-link.

Answer (score 0):

there is a sort of halfway house approach that i have used in one of my apps, where i wanted to be able to address buttons in a grid using an array in code, and like you, i wanted to design the look and feel in IB.

i did what you did in the sense that i put all the buttons on the view, and went as far as declaring an ivar, @property and @synhesize declaration for each one. since they were in a grid like you have described, what i did was name each one along the lines of button_1x1 button_1x2 etc (ie button_rxc as row x column if you think of a spreadsheet. the names are not important as you are only ever going to refer to them once in a method you call from viewDidLoad.

in that method, i created a bunch of NSArrays that held each button. for example:

```
    landscapeHidden = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       button_3x1, button_3x2,                  
                       button_4x1, button_4x2,                  
                       nil] retain];

    portraitHidden = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      button_1x3, button_1x4, 
                      button_2x3, button_2x4,

                      nil] retain];


    landscapeButtons = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        button_1x1, button_1x2, button_1x3, button_1x4, 
                        button_2x1, button_2x2, button_2x3, button_2x4, 
                        nil] retain];




    portraitButtons = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       button_1x1, button_1x2, 
                       button_2x1, button_2x2,  
                       button_3x1, button_3x2,  
                       button_4x1, button_4x2,
                       nil] retain];
```

i then used these arrays whenever i wanted to iterate them programatically.

the _hidden arrays are just used to indicate what buttons to hide when the display changes perspective - rather than move them around i figured it was faster to just hide the few that did not fit, and repaint them all.

as for interface builder, try this:

hold down control and click "File's Owner" once, and wait.

you will then get a large panel that you can use to wire connections to the view objects. i prefer using this method regardless of which direction i am connecting things up - ie if you drag from the objects directly the direction you drag in is not always convenient. this way you can easily view all the outlets at once. much easier from my perspective.

having said that it's pretty easy to loop through an array and assign targets or add gesture recognizers/ update titles/ colors/ whatever you like. i suppose you could also store them in a dictionary, (or have an array of dictionaries).

i went the array of having an array of dictionaries and the arrays of buttons you see above. on interface flips, the dictionaries don't change, but the buttons in the arrays get re-tagged, so any methods that have them as a "sender" can immediately get their dictionary data by indexing into the data array with

```
[myArray objectForIndex: ((UIButton*)sender).tag];
```

another trick - cmd-b build before you try doing anything in IB. this ensures it picks up things you have just edited, or files you have just added. sometimes i have had to clean/build to force an image to appear in the IB drop-downs. it's usually pretty good, but if you rename an image file, it's usually easier to delete it from the project and drag it in again, build (or clean build) then it should be good to go.